# Pearson Correlation and Point-Biserial correlation

Tags: correlation, multicollinearity

I have a question about correlation.

My research has 8 independent variables out of which 3 are continuous variables and 5 are dichotomous/binary variables. I have to check multicollinearity before running the regression model through correlation. can I use Pearson's correlation and point biserial correlation simultaneously, and show the results in the same table?

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I’ve voted to reopen this question, since point biserial correlation is a correlation between a continuous variable and a binary variable, and this is reasonable evidence to answer the question in the affirmative. // A bigger question is why you feel you must check for multicollinearity. What if it is not there? What if it is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point biserial correlation (magnitude) is Pearson correlation (magnitude) between a continuous variable and a binary variable that is encoded with numbers (e.g., as $0$ and $1$). Consequently, feel free to combine “regular” Pearson correlation and point biserial correlation in one table as if they were synonymous, since point biserial correlation really is a Pearson correlation.

I say that point biserial correlation is equal in magnitude to Pearson correlation because the numerical encoding of a categorical variable is ambiguous. Should dogs be coded as $0$ and cats as $1$? Should dogs be coded as $1$ and cats as $0$? You get the same Pearson correlation magnitude either way, but the sign will flip. Fortunately, this does not matter to an assessment of feature multicollinearity.